# DependencyService

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need DependencyService to use specific android functionality.

After Debug I see DependencyService is call, App is called too.

Why `DependencyService.Get<T>()` call `App()` ?

**IMyService.cs**

```cs
namespace SampleM3Scan.MobileApp.Services
{
    public interface IMyService
    {
    }
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```cs
using Android.Content;
using App1.MobileApp.Droid;
using App1.MobileApp.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyService))]
namespace App1.MobileApp.Droid
{
    internal class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly MyReceiver _myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

        public class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            private readonly App app = new App();

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send(app ,"item", intent.GetStringExtra("item"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using App1.MobileApp.Pages.Base;
using App1.MobileApp.Services;

namespace App1.MobileApp.Pages.Main
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : PageBase
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var myService = DependencyService.Get<IMyService>();
            BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel(myService);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are having trouble please.

Comment: I edit question with example.

Comment: And the error himself, I don't understand "error link Dictionary"

Comment: It's just a context but with this sample. App is call when DependencyService is call

Comment: maybe because MyReceiver  get a new instance and will build a new App() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myService = DependencyService.Get<IMyService>();
```

Will Give an instance of your `IMyService`.
In your case the `IMyService` will create a new `MyService`
As you can see in you `MyService` you have the following line :

```
 private readonly App scanApp = new App();
```

New App is created each time you will need to create a new `MyService` Class instance.

Comment: How do I upload information on the Xamarin.Forms with MessagingCenter side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195058/send-string-from-android-project-to-pcl-with-messagingcenter