# Xamarin Forms: Issue with reading notification data in foreground mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, foreground

Below is my MainActivity code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using static Firebase.Messaging.RemoteMessage;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.Nfc;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Content;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using NoticationDemo.Droid;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AndroidX.Core.App;

namespace NoticationDemo.Droid
{
    [Activity(
        Label = "NoticationDemo", 
        Icon = "@mipmap/icon", 
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
        MainLauncher = true,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "MainActivity";
        public bool isNotification = false;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            isNotification = false;
            IsPlayServicesAvailable();
            //background mode or killed mode
            CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent);

            if (!isNotification)
            {
                LoadApplication(new App("No Notification"));
            }
        }

        public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
        {
            int resultcode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultcode != ConnectionResult.Success)
            {
                if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultcode))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error:{GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultcode)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: play services not supported!");
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Play services available");
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            //foreground mode
            CreateNotificationFromIntent(intent);
        }

        void CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    var notificationName = intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationName");
                    var NotificatioKey = intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationKey");

                    Console.WriteLine("NotificationName:>>" + notificationName);
                    Console.WriteLine("NotificatioKey:>>" + NotificatioKey);

                    if (NotificatioKey == "Superman")
                    {
                        if (notificationName?.Length > 0)
                        {
                            isNotification = true;
                            LoadApplication(new App(notificationName));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}

[Service(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);
        Console.WriteLine($"Token received:>> {token}");
        SendRegistrationTokenToMainPRoject(token);
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        try
        {
            string body = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(message.GetNotification().Body.ToString()).Replace("&#39;", "'");
            string header = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(message.GetNotification().Title.ToString()).Replace("&#39;", "'");
            SendNotificatios(body, header, message.Data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:>>" + ex);
        }
    }

    public void SendNotificatios(string body, string Header, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
        }
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Mutable);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .SetContentTitle(Header)
                        .SetContentText(body)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
        else
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Utils.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetContentTitle(Header)
                        .SetContentText(body)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Utils.CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

            notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationTokenToMainPRoject(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            //Send Refresh to you FCM Server Here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.noticationdemo">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="NoticationDemo.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
      <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
      <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**Utils.cs**

```
public class Utils
{
    public static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "CB_FCM_CHANNEL";
    public static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
}
```

**Notification Payload:**

```
{
"to" : "device token",
"notification" : {
    "body" : "Hi1",
    "title": "Notification1"
},
"data" : {
    "NotificationName": "notification1",
     "NotificationKey" : "test"
    }
}
```

I am reading the NotificationName from the notification and passing it as an argument to App.xaml.cs and showing it on the UI of Mainpage.

```
public App(string notificationName)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MainPage(notificationName);
}

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(string notificationName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        notificationname_label.Text = notificationName; 
    }
}
```

**My issue is the first notification in foreground mode is always showing for all the notifications receiving in foreground mode.**

For eg: I received Notification1 in foreground mode. If I tap on it the notification 1 data will read and it will show on the UI. Again if I receive a new notification, Notification2, if I tap on that, the notification 1 data is again showing on the UI. Always reading the very first notification data in foreground mode. No such issue in background mode.

Here is my [demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ffxAQqmcq1yNp3nZF4MdA8WIUMtDqAg/view?usp=sharing) and [postman collection](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mdeusXY79wJpJ2pETMUuG04gfN6aWRXB/view?usp=sharing) to recreate this issue.

**How to recreate this issue:**

- Run the demo project into an android device and fetch your device FCM token. Add it on the postman collection APIs, on `your device token` part.
- Then send API named Notification 1 in foreground mode. When tap on it then notification1 text will show on the UI.
- Then if you send Notification 2 in foreground mode and tap on it again notification1 text will show on the UI instead of notification2.
- **The initial notification data is showing for all the notifications received in foreground mode.** But no such issue in background mode and everything is working fine on background mode.

Referred blogs:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#handle-incoming-notifications-on-android

**Update**

I have added the `MessagingCenter.Send` inside of `CreateNotificationFromIntent` like below:

```
void CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.Extras != null)
    {
        foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
        {
            var notificationName = intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationName");
            var NotificationKey = intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationKey");

            Console.WriteLine("NotificationName:>>" + notificationName);
            Console.WriteLine("NotificationKey:>>" + NotificationKey);

            if (NotificationKey == "test")
            {
                if (notificationName?.Length > 0)
                {
                    isNotification = true;
                    MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "NotificationName", notificationName);
                    LoadApplication(new App(notificationName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated `MainPage` contents with `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` part.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(string notificationName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //notificationname_label.Text = notificationName;
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(this, "NotificationName", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            notificationname_label.Text = arg;
        });
    }
}
```

But when tap on notification the notification name is not showing on the UI. When I debug it by adding breakpoints, the `MessagingCenter.Send` and `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` are invoking infinte times, but the notification name is not visible on mainpage UI.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is the first notification in foreground mode is always showing for all the notifications receiving in foreground mode.

This is because you set the UI label in the MainPage's constructor by `notificationname_label.Text = notificationName;`. When the app run in foreground, the App.cs and MainPage's constructor will only be called when the MainPage initializes first time.

So you can refer to [official document about using INotificationManager helper class to receive the notification](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/INotificationManager.cs).

In addition, you can also using the MessagingCenter to do that. Here is a case about [using MessagingCenter to notify UI that the notifiction is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284345/17455524).

**Update:**

If you use the `MessagingCenter`, you can send the new notification name when you receive it.  And subscribe it in the MainPage's constructor:

**Send the new notification name:**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "NotificationName","the new notification name you want to send")
```

**Receive the new notification name:**

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Subscribe to a message (which the ViewModel has also subscribed to) to display an alert
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "NotificationName", async (sender, arg) =>
            {
                notificationname_label.Text = arg; 
            });
        }
```

For more information, you can refer to [using MessagingCenter to notify UI that the notification is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284345/17455524) and the [official sample about the MessagingCenter](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UsingMessagingCenter/UsingMessagingCenter/MainPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: Can you explain little more? I didn't get completely. On where I need to use the `MessagingCenter` and `INotificationManager`? Is it possible to update the demo with this fix and share?

Comment: @SreejithSree You can check the update part in my answer. And you can read the [official document about the MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) at first.

Comment: Why you are using diferent keys on `MessagingCenter.Send` and `MessagingCenter.Subscribe`, Is it by mistake? And why the value is not sending on `MessagingCenter.Send` ? Without sending how we will get it on MainPage?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It should be `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(this, "NotificationName", async (sender, arg) =>` @SreejithSree

Comment: Still i am confused on send part. Why the value is not sending on `MessagingCenter.Send`? Without sending value how we will get it on MainPage?

Comment: I have added detail code about sending and receiving message. You can try it. @SreejithSree

Comment: And you can refer to this case about [Sending string from Android project to PCL with MessagingCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195058/send-string-from-android-project-to-pcl-with-messagingcenter). @SreejithSree

Comment: I tried it on my side but still no luck. I have updated the findings on the question, could you please check. I have added the  `MessagingCenter.Send` inside of `CreateNotificationFromIntent`, Is that the correct place?

Comment: Did you try to debug to check if the `CreateNotificationFromIntent` method executed when you receive the second or third message? @SreejithSree

Comment: And please change the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(this` to `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current` in the MainPage.cs. @SreejithSree

Comment: Tried again, but no luck. Nothing is displayed on the `MainPage`.

Comment: Did you try to debug to check if the `MessagingCenter.Send` method executed or not when you receive the second or third message? @SreejithSree

Comment: `MessagingCenter.Send` is not firing when the notification receiving. It is inside `CreateNotificationFromIntent` , so it will fire only when we tap on a notification.

Comment: I feel we are on the wrong root. My issue is in the data we are getting in foreground mode when we tap on it. Initial data is always getting in foreground mode. So if we use `MessagingCenter` to send data, at that time also wrong data is passing. Only medium is changing from `arguments` to `MessagingCenter`.

Comment: Did you check the first part of my answer? The problem is the mainpage's constructor and the `LoadApplication(new App(notificationName));` will only call once when the app is running in the foreground. @SreejithSree

Comment: I have added `MessagingCenter.Send` inside the `CreateNotificationFromIntent`. Is that correct? I have already updated the question with my latest implementation, could you please check that and let me know If I made any mistakes.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint at the `MessagingCenter.Send` and debug to check it will execute or not when you receive the second or third notification. I can't make sure when will the `CreateNotificationFromIntent` method be called. @SreejithSree

Comment: When receiving notification `MessagingCenter.Send` is not invoking, it is firing only when we tap on a notification.

Comment: Below is the output box response after tapping notification 3. But initially I send notification 2.
 `15:06:53:441 NotificationName:>>notification2
 15:06:53:442 NotificationKey:>>test` So do you think the issue is in mainpage's constructor?

Comment: Did you mean when you tapped the notification, the `MessagingCenter.Send` was called and still sent the first notifiction name? @SreejithSree

Comment: If so, you can declare a string variable in the MainActivity and when you receive the new notification, you can set the variable's value as the notification name and use the `MessagingCenter.Send` to send the variable. @SreejithSree

Comment: That approach I tried already and it will fail when multiple notifications. When multiple notifications received, only the last notification values will be in the string variable.

Comment: So you want to show the notification name which you tap on? If so, you need to use the [Notification.Action](app) to send the notification name. @SreejithSree

Comment: I didn't get this `[Notification.Action](app)`. Can you explain little more?

Comment: Sorry for my careless. You can check the official document about [Notification.Action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action) and send the notification name with the messagingcenter when the notification is tapped. @SreejithSree

Comment: I didn't get a clear idea about the usage of `Notification.Action`. Could you please explain a little more? Where I should use this? Using this how can I read the data with keys?

Comment: Use it when you create the notification. Did you read the official document at first? @SreejithSree